# want to install SharePoint 2013 with an activ directory existent

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I want to install SharePoint 2013, but I have a few questions:

- how to link the installation of SharePoint 2013 to an active directory exist
- how to avoid the traps of the installation
- what are the steps to follow in detail

It's all new to me

I have already installed a 2012 and sql 2012 server

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What u mean by linking to AD? Are u installing it on same server where AD installed?

Comment: helloi m not installing SharePoint on the same server. my AD is installed on another server

Comment: i want to receive email alerts when a answer is given , how can i do it in stackexchange ?

Comment: if you can help me step by step it will be famous

Answer (score 3):

**Before you start. you should**

- Make sure that the current machine specification match with the [minimum requirement of installing SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx)

**To install SharePoint 2013 with SP1 on Windows Server 2012**

- Install Windows server 2012 for more details check [Install Windows server 2012 guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/06/installing-windows-server-2012-step-by-step/)
- [Configure Active Directory](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2012/configuring-active-directory-ad-ds-in-windows-server-2012/) (you can install it on the same machine only for dev environment , but [it's not supported on the production environment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2764086)  ).
- [Create Service Account.](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-service-accounts-best-practices-explained.html)
- [Install SQL Server 2012](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/31/sql-server-2012-setup/).
- Install SharePoint 2013 prerequests (Make sure you have an internet connection to can install prerequisites online by clicking on install software Prerequisites).
- After the prerequisite has been installed successfully ,  Follow the mentioned steps at [Installing SharePoint 2013 – Step by Step](https://collab365.community/step-by-step-installation-of-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-server-1/) or wache this [vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u81RqLqWLC8) to complete the installaton and configuration of Sharepoint 2013 over Windwos Servr 2012 and SQl Server 2012.